# Command line to kill Adobe Reader process only if it was not already running

Tags: pdf, command-line, adobe, acrobat

I am trying some cmd.exe coding for the first time. I created a registry key, which contains a command called by a custom protocol handler­. What I'm trying to accomplish : Call Adobe Reader which will automatically print a pdf to a given printer. This part already works. I'm using powershell to download the pdf locally from a URL. I also want to kill the Acrobat process once i'm done, but only if it was already opened BEFORE calling my command, so I don't kill the process if the user already has a pdf opened when calling the protocol handler via Chrome.

Excuse the more than ugly formatting, a one-line command is a must in my case, I can't make a batch file or .ps1 file.

```
cmd /V /C set exists="0" & (tasklist | find "AcroRd32.exe" > nul) & if 
(%%ERRORLEVEL%%==0 set exists="1") & set myvar=%1 & call set 
myvar=%%myvar:ie:=%% & call set printer=%%myvar:*@@@=%% & call set 
printer=^"%%printer%%^" & call set printer=%%printer:'=%% & call start 
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command $url=%%myvar%%; $pdf = 
$url.split('@'); md -Force c:\TempPdf "| Out-Null"; (New-Object 
System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($pdf,'C:/TempPdf/PatientLabel.pdf'); &  
timeout /t 2 & call start acrord32.exe /n /t  C:/TempPdf/PatientLabel.pdf 
%%printer%% & timeout /t 2 & (if !exists!=="1" taskkill /f /im acrord32.exe)
```

The part which does not work is the tasklist/taskkill. I want to set the %%exists%% variable to 1 if I can find the process running before starting AcroRd32.exe and kill it after printing if %%exists%%=1. I think this might just not be working because of the execution time/parse, but I don't really know how to use /V and !var! anyway. The exists and ERRORLEVEL variables don't seem to expand.

Thanks for the help !